# Search bar tableview array index out of range

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, search

I'm trying to create a search bar in my `Tableview`, but it's not giving me a result of filtration, Table is empty

> fatal error: Array index out of range

I thing that something goes wrong in Tableview update fuction or filterContent, but can't understand what. Could somebody explain it to me?

```
        var find: [List] = []        //my core data file
        var searchResult: [List] = [] //my core data file

        let context: NSManagedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
        var detailViewController: MainVC? = nil
        var frc : NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()

        var searchController: UISearchController!

        func getFetchResultsController() ->NSFetchedResultsController {
            frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: listFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

            return frc
        }

        func listFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest{
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest (entityName: "List")
            let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "item", ascending: true)
            fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
            return fetchRequest
        }

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            frc = getFetchResultsController()
            frc.delegate = self
            do {
                try frc.performFetch()
            } catch {}
            if let split = self.splitViewController {
                let controllers = split.viewControllers
                self.detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? MainVC
            }
            searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
            tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
            searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
            searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

        func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }


        // MARK: - Table view data source

        override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            let numberOfSections = frc.sections?.count
            return numberOfSections!
        }

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            if searchController.active {
                return searchResult.count
            } else {
                //return find.count
                let numberOfRowsInSection = frc.sections?[section].numberOfObjects
                return numberOfRowsInSection!
            }

            // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows

        }


        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {      
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)       
            let search = (searchController.active) ? searchResult[indexPath.row] : frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! List
       print(search)
        //Configure the cell..
       cell.textLabel!.text = search.item
        let qty = search.qty
        let address = search.address

        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Dukan Sayi: \(qty)\(address)"
        return cell
}
        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
            if searchController.active {
                return false
            } else {
                return true
            }
        }
        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

            let managedObject : NSManagedObject = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject

            context.deleteObject(managedObject)

            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {}
        }
 func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
      if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text {
        filterContent(searchText)
         print(searchText)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
  }
  func filterContent(searchText: String) {
   searchResult = find!.filter({ ( a: List) -> Bool in
        let nameMatch = a.item.rangeOfString(searchText, options:   NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
        return nameMatch != nil
        })

   }
```

Comment: nobody knows what can be problem here, because I tried everything, and mistake somewhere near me, but I can fix it.

Comment: In `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` what happens if `searchController.active == true`?

Comment: existing values disappear. And when I entering one of my values it doesn't come to tableview. Table still empty.

Comment: It should returns 1 in that case. Plus, it would help if you can debug exactly which method causes the error.

Comment: And when I pressing cancel, my cells returning

Comment: program not showing me any error, how can I check which method engaged me

Comment: Use breakpoints. Or a printf() in each methods and see what's the last one before the crash.

Comment: all methods works without crashing, just searchResult func giving me zero

Comment: searchResult not nil, it means that program finding result, but cant show in table

Comment: if searchController.active {
            print(searchResult?.count)
        return searchResult!.count
Giving Optional (0)